# Antichains of maximal size in the set of all finite subsets of a singular cardinal

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $P = (P, \le)$ be a partially ordered set. A subset $T$ of $P$ is called:

1. *cofinal* (in $P$), if for all $x \in P$ there is a $t \in T$ such that $x \le t$,
2. *antichain*, if for all $x, y \in T$, $x \le y$ implies $x = y$.

Now let $\kappa$ be an uncountable cardinal,
$P = [\kappa]^{< \omega}$ be the set of all finite subsets of $\kappa$, partially ordered by inclusion.
For $T \subset P, n < \omega$, define $T_n = \{a \in T: |a| = n\}$.

**Question:**  *Let $T \subset P$ be cofinal in $P$.
Does $T$ contain an antichain of size $\kappa$* ?

**Notes.**

1. It is well-known (and easy to see) that $|T| = |P| = \kappa$.
2. The question would be trivial, if we just considered $P$ instead of $T$, since
   $P_1 = \{ \{\alpha\}: \alpha < \kappa\}$ is an antichain
   of size $\kappa$.
3. This is false for $\kappa = \omega$, since
   $T = \{ \{0, \ldots, n \}: n \in \omega \}$ is linearly ordered and
   cofinal in    $[\omega]^{< \omega}$.
4. This is true, if $ \omega < \text{cf}(\kappa)$ (in particular, if
   $\kappa$ is regular uncountable).
   [Since $T = \bigcup_{n < \omega} T_n$, there is a $n < \omega$, such that
   $|T_n| = \kappa$.]
5. Hence, the first interesting case is $\kappa = \aleph_\omega$.
   (And I believe the question boils down to this case.)
6. For $\kappa = \aleph_\omega$, such an easy attempt
   as in 4. does not work:
   for $n < \omega$ let
   $S_n = \{a \subset \aleph_n: |a| = n\}$.
   Then $\bigcup_{n < \omega} S_n$ is cofinal in $P$,
   but
   $|(\bigcup_{n < \omega} S_n)_m| = |S_m| = \aleph_m$
   for each $m < \omega$.
7. $T$ contains an antichain of size $\lambda$
   for each cardinal $\lambda < \kappa$.
   [Use the same partition of $T$ as in 4.]

Comment: Nevermind, I missed the requirement for $T$ to be cofinal.

Comment: By https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151929/showing-that-the-least-cardinal-kappa-such-that-a-specific-poset-has-no-stron there is also an antichain of size $\kappa$ for singular $\kappa$.

Comment: Nevermind, i did not consider your definition of "Antichain". In most contexts, when set theorists refer to an antichain in a poset, they are talking about what is called "strong antichain" in the preceding post. Of course, the poset does not contain any strong antichains because any two elements are compatible via $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ does indeed contain an antichain of size $\kappa$.  This appears to not really be about cofinality, and is rather an argument about cardinality in general, i.e., any uncountable subset $T\subseteq [\kappa]^{< \omega}$ will have an antichain of the same cardinality $|T|$.

Here is a proof.

Given subsets $A,B\subseteq T$, denote by $R(A,B)$ the set of all $b\in B$ such that $a\not\leq b,b\not\leq a$ for every $a\in A$.  These should be thought of as the remaining elements of $B$ that are candidates for our antichain once we decide to include $A$.

Now, let $n_i$ be the subsequence of indices for which $|T_{n_i}|$ is uncountable, and note that $|T|=|\bigcup_i T_{n_i}|$. We could actually still make the ensuing induction argument even if this subsequence were finite, but in any case we lose no generality assuming the subsequence is infinite, as otherwise (as noted in the comments below) we have some $n$ with $|T_n|=|T|$, and we could then simply take $T_n$ as our antichain.

For each stage $i$, we will inductively construct $S_i\subseteq T_{n_i}$ so that

1. $\bigcup_{k\leq i}S_k$ is an antichain.
2. $|S_i|=|T_{n_i}|$.
3. For each $j>i$, $\left|R\left(\bigcup_{k\leq i}S_k,T_{n_j}\right)\right|=|T_{n_j}|$.

It will then follow that $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty S_k$ is an antichain with the desired cardinality $|T|$.

Having defined $S_k$ for all $k<i$, we define $S_i$ as follows.

Let $\lambda=|T_{n_i}|=\left|R\left(\bigcup_{k<i}S_k, T_{n_i}\right)\right|$, with the second equality holding trivially if $i=0$ and by Property 3) for stage $i-1$ otherwise. Let $$f\colon \lambda\times \lambda \to R\left(\bigcup_{k<i}S_k, T_{n_i}\right)$$ be a bijection.  Let $S_{i}^\alpha$ denote $f(\{\alpha\}\times \lambda)$ for each $\alpha\in \lambda$.

We observe that for every $j>i$, there are at most finitely many $\alpha$ for which $$\left|R\left(\left(\bigcup_{k<i} S_k\right)\cup S_{i}^\alpha,T_{n_j}\right)\right|<|T_{n_j}|.\tag{P}$$  In fact, there can be at most $\binom{n_j}{n_i}$.  To see this, first note that given a finite collection of such indices $\alpha_m$, since we have
$$\left|\bigcup_m R\left(\left(\bigcup_{k<i} S_k\right)\cup S_{i}^{\alpha_m},T_{n_j}\right)\right|
< |T_{n_j}|=\left|R\left(\bigcup_{k<i} S_k,T_{n_j}\right)\right|,$$

there is some $$t\in R\left(\bigcup_{k<i} S_k,T_{n_j}\right)\backslash \bigcup_m R\left(\left(\bigcup_{k<i} S_k\right)\cup S_{i}^{\alpha_m},T_{n_j}\right).$$  Therefore $t\in T_{n_j}$ is comparable to one element in each of the disjoint sets $S_{i}^{\alpha_m}\subseteq T_{n_i}$, and an element in $T_{n_j}$ can only be comparable to $\binom{n_j}{n_i}$ elements of $T_{n_i}$.

It follows that there are at most countably many indices $\alpha$ for which (P) holds for ***any*** $j>i$, so we may choose some index $\alpha_0\in \lambda$ for which (P) always fails. We let $S_i=S_i^{\alpha_0}$, and argue our three inductive properties are satisfied.

Indeed, for Property 1), $S_i$ was chosen from elements of $R\left(\bigcup_{k<i}S_k, T_{n_i}\right)$, which are not comparable with each other, nor with any members of $S_k$ for $k<i$, so $\bigcup_{k\leq i}S_k$ is an antichain.

Property 2) is ensured by the construction of $S_i$ via the bijection $f$.

Property 3) is ensured since (P) always fails.

Thus the induction can proceed, and we are finished.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very nice and clever proof.
Just two tiny remarks:
1. W.l.o.g., we can assume that $T_n$ is uncountable for infinitely many $n$.
   (Since otherwise, there is an $n$ such that $|T_n| = |T|$.)
2. Either the induction should start with $S_{-1} = \emptyset$
   or define $S_0$ already as in the induction step, 
   since $S_0 = \emptyset$ contradicts 2.

Comment: @Ulli Thanks, glad you liked it!  I was being silly about the base case, we don’t really need it as we essentially are doing strong induction here.  We could do the induction on a finite sequence as well, but of course we don’t need to for reason you gave.  I updated answer to clarify both these points.

Answer (score 2):

A. Hajnal, Proof of a conjecture of S. Ruziewicz, Fund, Mat. 50 (1961), 123-128 ([pdf](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm50/fm50112.pdf)) proved the result paraphrased below:

**Hajnal's set-mapping theorem.** Given a set $T$ with $|T|=\kappa\ge\aleph_0$, a cardinal $\lambda\lt\kappa$, and a mapping $f:T\to\mathcal P(T)$ such that $x\notin f(x)$ and $|f(x)|\lt\lambda$ for all $x\in T$, there is a set $A\subseteq T$ such that $|A|=\kappa$ and $f(x)\cap A=\varnothing$ for all $x\in A$.

Taking $\lambda=\aleph_0$ and $f(x)=\mathcal P(x)\setminus\{x\}$, we get the following corollary of Hajnal's theorem:

**Corollary.** Any collection of finite sets of cardinality $\kappa\gt\aleph_0$ contains an antichain of cardinality $\kappa$.

Comment: Thank you very much also for this very nice conclusion from Hajnal's result (+1). However, I prefer M W's answer, since it is self-contained, and I need not go through this very complicated proof of Hajnal (a theorem, which even Erdös couldn't proof in (ZFC) must be complicated!), although some of the easier versions cited in this paper would suffice here.

Comment: I agree that the check mark should go to the self-contained proof; I just wanted to add the Hajnal reference to the record. I haven't had time to study MW's proof, and I've forgotten Hajnal's proof which I read many years ago, but I wonder if they are essentially the same, if MW has rediscovered Hajnal's theorem is the special setting that you asked about.

Comment: There are several places in M W's proof, where it is essential that only finite sets are involved. Therefore, I doubt that this proof really rediscovers the whole strength of Hajnal's proof. But perhaps it rediscovers the earlier versions mentioned in this paper for $\lambda = \aleph_0$ ? I haven't thought about this, perhaps this result itself might actually imply the $\lambda = \aleph_0$ version of Hajnal's theorem?

Comment: Even in the case $\lambda=\aleph_0$, I'm a bit pessimistic about recovering Hajnal's result.  The biggest difficulty is not the finiteness per se, it's that in my proof, I rely heavily on the fact that we have ready-made sets $T_n$ for which $x,y\in T_n$ implies $x$ and $y$ can both be in an antichain together.  Given a general $f$ as in Hajnal's theorem, its not clear what the anologue for those sets would be.  We might be tempted to define $T_n=\{x\mid |f(x)|=n\}$, but this gives no guarantee that $x\notin f(y)$ or $y\notin f(x)$ for $x,y\in T_n$.